# FancyBox and custom tooltip together wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using FancyBox and a very simple jQuery tooltip together, if not clicked on images yet, the tooltip is for showing the "titles" on the page. If clicked a image the fancybox will take over the title to display title tag "inside".
The title doesn't show up once clicked the image, but the tooltip is OK. Is it possible to make them work together?

Here is the jQuery for tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    tooltip();
});

this.tooltip = function(){  
    $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";                                      
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip").fadeIn("fast");       
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;        
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")

    });         
};
```

Here is my FancyBox code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#example8").fancybox({
            'titlePosition': 'over'
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is HTML code:

```
<a id="example8" class="tooltip" href="./example/8_b.jpg" title="Sed vel sapien vel sem tempus placerat eu ut tortor. Nulla facilisi. Sed adipiscing, turpis ut cursus molestie, sem eros viverra mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien enim nec est. ras pulvinar placerat diam eu consectetur.">
    <img class="last" alt="example7" src="./example/8_s.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: You appear to have an extra }); after  tooltip();
Would be best if you could make a www.jsfiddle.com of the issue so we can work on it easier.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ynXvx/7/ Tooltip doesnt work on jsfiddle

Comment: The imports for fancybox weren't working for me so I redid those and reformated the code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/ynXvx/8/ not sure what the tooltip is supposed to do though, do you have a link for the js file?

Comment: just to clarify: does fancybox show the title?

Comment: yes, if you remove jQuery for tooltip codes you will see the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable on top of your javascript, e.g.

```
var thisTitle;
```

then use that variable to clone the `title` within your tooltip script (instead of `this.t`) like

```
this.tooltip = function(){  
    $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
        thisTitle = this.title;
        this.title = "";                                      
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ thisTitle +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip").fadeIn("fast");       
    },
    function(){
        this.title = thisTitle;        
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")

    });         
}
```

In your fancybox custom script, use the `titleFormat` API option to pull the `title` from the `thisTitle` variable like

```
$("a#example8").fancybox({
   "titlePosition": 'over',
   "titleFormat"  : function(){
      return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">'+thisTitle+'</span>'
    }
});
```

all together?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisTitle;
$(document).ready(function(){
 tooltip();
 $("a#example8").fancybox({
   "titlePosition": "over",
   "titleFormat": function(){
      return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">'+thisTitle+'</span>'
    }
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready

this.tooltip = function(){  
    $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
        thisTitle = this.title;
        this.title = "";                                      
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ thisTitle +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip").fadeIn("fast");       
    },
    function(){
        this.title = thisTitle;        
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")
    });         
}
</script>
```